# jquery: two click function

Tags: jquery

why i click on "close" div, don't show "basic text"?
in short, why don't work second "click" function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sp").click(function(){
                $("#info").html("<div><div id='close'>Close</div><div>new text</div></div>");
            });

            $("#close").click(function(){
                $("#info").html("<div>basic text</div>");
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="sp">Click</p>
    <div id="info">
        <div>basic text</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the `live()` function for this:

```
$("#sp").click(function(){
    $("#info").html("<div><div id='close'>Close</div><div>new text</div></div>");
});

$("#close").live('click', function(){
    $("#info").html("<div>basic text</div>");
});
```

Your element with the id `closed` is created after the click event handler has been attached (to nothing in this case). You'll need to ensure that it will be also attached to dynamically created elements. And for this you can use `live()`

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble, so you could just place a handler directly on `info` that looks for click on elements with the ID `close`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sp").click(function(){
        $("#info").html("<div><div id='close'>Close</div><div>new text</div></div>");
    });

    $("#info").click(function(e){
        if( e.target.id === "close" ) {
            $(this).html("<div>basic text</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

As an alternative, you could use [`delegate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which does essentially the same thing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sp").click(function(){
        $("#info").html("<div><div id='close'>Close</div><div>new text</div></div>");
    });

    $("#info").delegate('#close','click',function(e){
        $(this).parent().html("<div>basic text</div>");
    });
});
```

Ultimately the best solution would be to have *all* the markup on the page when it loads, and just [`show()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it as necessary. This is much better than destroying and recreating reusable content.

Answer (score 0):

Because close doesn't exist when the click is set. Use the live function instead.

```
$("#close").live("click", function(){
  $("#info").html("<div>basic text</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `close` element is added dynamically, and not present in the DOM on page-load.

If you amend the code a little, to:

```
$("#close").live('click',
    function(){
        $("#info").html("<div>basic text</div>");
});
```

It should work fine.

[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) allows events to be bound to elements not-yet created/present in the DOM.